# Why Microsoft Word for Mac won't open on other computers

Tags: macos, ms-office

When I open up Word for Mac now, it automatically will open the most recent files that were opened up (as many as 10 to 15 files).

What command or operation stops word from opening these recent files automatically?

Comment: This cloud be the saved state information if you quit the app with those windows open. Have a look here and let us know if one answer works - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/79834/stop-office-for-mac-from-loading-with-earlier-documents-on-top-of-the-one-i-open

Answer (score 1):

When you are ready to quit Microsoft Word, select the “Word” menu and hold down the Option/Alt (⌥) key.

That will change this menu:

[image]

to this one:

[image]

Comment: Is this new in the 2011 version?  On Office 2008, the alt key doesn't do anything.

Comment: What version of Mac OS X are you using?

Comment: I have 10.6.8 on my desk.  I can probably find someone running 10.7 or 10.8 with Office 2008 to check if that makes a difference.

Comment: (Since tone of voice is absent in text, let me say I'm not suggesting you’ve done anything wrong, just to help you get best help.) My solution will only help with 10.7 or later. You should always mention software and OS X version, especially when you’re running old versions. I suspect most people are like me and will assume that you are running the latest version of the OS and latest version of whatever software package you are asking about. Unfortunately I have no idea what the problem could be on Office 2008 on Mac OS X 10.6.8.

Answer (score 1):

I had a user that was having this problem. Suddenly whenever she opened up Word 2011, every document would open to the point where the app would error and stop working entirely to the point where she couldn't use Word at all.

I found the disabling the Resume All Windows function from System Preferences and the Shut Down menu fixed the problem. You can found out how to do this [Here](http://www.lauramartin.co.nz/how-to-stop-word-2011-for-mac-from-opening-all-recent-documents/).
Hope this helps!